# Exchange on SBS2003 not receiving mail, but sending via telnet works

Tags: email, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

Last week we had a problem on our SBS2003 server where our external connection dropped out and I was only able to restore it by running netsh winsock reset catalog and netsh int ip reset.

Thinking all was well, I went home for the weekend and came in today to find that we haven't received any external emails since before the original problems occurred. There are plenty of examples of this on the internet, usually to do with a firewall issue, but the odd thing here is that when I connect using telnet I can send an email and it goes straight through and into my inbox. When I send an email from Gmail or Hotmail nothing comes through at all. Internal emails are also unaffected, as are outgoing emails. There have also been a couple of emails that have come through for other users, both out-of-office replies, if that's relevant.

I've run the CEICW several times, checked all the NIC settings, but no joy. Before I give up trying to fix this and reinstall the whole server, has anyone come across this problem before? I have only found fleeting references to this in previous searches and no real answers.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Just to be sure: When you telnet, you do that from outside your network?

Comment: Time to upgrade.  [That dinosaur is out of extended support](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2013/09/25/information-about-sbs-2003-product-support-lifecycle.aspx) ... and I'd hope that the fact that it's not working would be justification enough to replace it with something better, and actually supported.

Comment: An upgrade would be nice, but it's our main server and it would take longer to wring the money out of our finance department than to just reinstall it. I may use the 'it's on its way out' argument when pushing for a new server in future though!

Comment: And yes, I am telnetting from outside the network.

Comment: Have you verified that your external DNS (A and MX) records are correct, that they resolve to the correct ip address, that the firewall is configured correctly for NAT/Port Forwarding, and that the server has the correct ip settings? Start from one end and work your way to the other checking and verifying everything.

Comment: Yes, the A record points to a different server outside our network, and the MX record works fine. Sending a test email through the Wormly SMTP testing tool comes through to my inbox as well, presumably because it uses telnet. Running nslookup -q=mx outside the network comes back with the correct address.